# Prove that x{n} is convergent

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence

So I'm currently studying for my midterms and I found the following question from my practice set which I'm unable to solve:

Prove that the following sequence $(x_{n})$ is convergent. Let
$$x_{n} = \frac{\sin 1}{2} + \frac{\sin 2}{2^2} + \frac{\sin 3}{2^3} + ... + \frac{\sin n}{2^n}$$

This is the first time I've seen such a sequence, how does one go about proving such questions? Do I need to first prove that the sequence is monotonic?

Comment: $\dfrac{|\sin{n}|}{2^n}\leq \dfrac{1}{2^n}$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The series converges absolutely and thus it converges, since

$$\left|\frac{\sin k}{2^k}\right|\le\frac1{2^k}$$

Apply now the comparison test and we're done.

Comment: Thanks alot! looks like i'm a little slow on math here >< i can't seem to get the hang of proving-type questions at all :/

Comment: My pleasure....